# Is there an efficient way to create histogram of thousands of columns on a table with millions of rows?

Tags: python, pyspark, google-bigquery, bigdata

I am new to large data. I have a few large tables (~TB scale), with data for different months, that I am trying to analyze for feature drift. I am specifically trying to calculate KL divergence of corresponding columns for two consecutive months. Prior to calculating KL divergence I need to get the probability distribution of the columns, which means creating a histogram where I can have bins and counts. The normalized array of counts would give me the probability distribution that I need in order to calculate KL divergence using scipy entropy function.

The tables that I am analyzing have millions of rows and around 2000 columns/features and are all in BigQuery. I have tried approaching this problem using two different tools.

(I am using Python for all my approaches)

1- I tried using Pyspark and it was taking 70 seconds to calculate bins and counts for just one single column of one table. This way it would take weeks to do it for all the features and tables that I have.

2- I leveraged the big query python api and created python function to create long queries in batches (e.g. batches of 10 columns) to calculate bins and counts for each column. For calculating bins and counts with big query I used "CASE WHEN" functionality of bigquery and set my values to predefined bin centers. Following is an example

```
case when col_name1>=1 and col_name1<2 then bin_center_array[0]
     when col_name1>=2 and col_name1<3 then bin_center_array[1]
     ...
```

Using big query the calculations were only taking 0.5 seconds per column (less than 2hours for the whole calculation instead of a week). However, if I did batches of 10 on two tables I would run out of QueryQuotaPerDayPerUser after about 10 batches (note that I need 2000/10=200 batches). And If I increased the batch size to larger values I would get "BadRequest: 400 resources exceeded...." error (Note: each batch essentially produces a long query, the larger the batch the longer the query).

I am not sure how to tackle this. Any help or suggestion is appreciated

Comment: One possible quick detour would be adopting sampling methods such as [FARM_FINGERPRINT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/hash_functions) or [TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-sampling).

Comment: Would increasing the [quota Limit](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#query_jobs:~:text=Maximum%20number%20of%20concurrent%20batch%20queries) for concurrent batch queries help in your setup?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you more have a quota issue than a performance issue.

If I correctly understand you run into a quota exceeded error as defined [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/custom-quotas#how_custom_quotas_are_enforced) because you try to scan a table that is too big regarding the daily quota set by your bigquery administrator.

If you're open for quota increase you can file a request through your console following the [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#query_jobs:%7E:text=Maximum%20number%20of%20concurrent%20batch%20queries).
If you cannot make this quota increased by your administrator, [table sampling](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/table-sampling#using_table_sampling) might help.

If performance is the issue, you can easily run bigquery queries in parallel from python. With 50 parallel queries your 2h job will only last 2.4 minutes. Consider using [batch query mode](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-queries#batch) not to encounter « too many concurrent requests » issue.